# Toggle Macro to Hide/Unhide Select Columns

Tags: excel, vba, toggle, hide

Am wanting to have a macro/button that toggles between hiding and unhiding select columns.  I had something similar that hid/unhid rows but can't figure this one out.

```
Sub PrintToggle()
With ActiveSheet
    With Range("C:C,E:E,H:H,L:O,U:U,AA:AA,AF:AF,AI:AK").Columns
        If .EntireColumn.Hidden Then
            .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End With
```

End Sub

This use to at least hide the columns but after saving and re-opening, it now hides the entire sheet.  I can't get it to stop doing this let along unhide the same columns.  Thanks!

Comment: The `.Columns` is redundant but otherwise works fine for me.

Comment: This is frustrating.  I restarted and had only that file open.  Ran it and it's still hiding everything with no way to unhide.  I have to keep opening the last saved version.

Comment: You're missing a `.` in front of `Range`, or just get rid of the `With ActiveSheet` btw.

Comment: If I do this from VBE `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,C:C").Address`, I get `Application-defined or object-defined error`(1004). But when I do this ``Debug.Print Range("A:A,C:C").Address`` I get `Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`(1004). But I figured out that I need to use the semi-colon (**;**) instead of the comma.

Comment: No Repo, this works as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

loop over a cell in each row worked for me

```
Sub PrintToggle()

    Dim r As Range
    
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("C1,E1,H1,L1:O1,U1,AA1,AF1,AI1:AK1")
        If r.EntireColumn.Hidden Then
            r.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            r.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```